# How to list opentype font feature names from a font using opentype.js?

Tags: javascript, fonts

In a JS environment I want to list the a font's 'font features' so that I can set them with [font-feature-settings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-feature-settings) css.

Is there a better alternative than [opentype.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/opentype.js)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've created an [opentype.features.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/opentype.features.js) npm package, which does more than opentype.js, with respect to listing font features.

Along with listing the feature tags, it also lists the feature descriptions and option labels.

Example output:

`...,{"tag":"cv13","description":"Cap B-hook alt","options":["Lowercase style"]},...`

Answer (score 0):

Font features can be extracted from the `GSUB` table.

Here is a simple example listing the font feature names from

```
import opentype from 'opentype.js'

async function listFontFeatures()
{    
    const font = await  opentype.load("C:\\Windows\\Fonts\\arial.ttf");
    const featureNames = [...Array.from(new Set(font.tables.gsub.features.map((f: any) => f.tag)))]

    for (const name of featureNames)        
        console.log(name);
}

listFontFeatures();
```

This displays the 4 char font feature codes :

c2sc
calt
ccmp
dlig
dnom
fina
frac
init
isol
liga
lnum
locl
medi
numr
onum

Human readable names can be looked up from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/opentype/spec/features_ae)